# react boostrap date range picker(customize showDropdows property)

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

So my question is :

> Is there a way to customise the showDropdowns in react boostrap date
> range picker ?
>
> the scroll bar dropdown come with a default one and i want to add some
> styles to it ..is this possible ??

Answer (score 0):

By using custom cssClass property. and also you can use the calendar’s renderDayCell event to customize the appearance of the each day cell.

for more info https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/datepicker/customization/